# VBA can't import range into array when the code is run with F5 but it will if it's run line by line (F8)

Tags: excel, vba

So as the title indicates, when run with F5, the VBA code I've written prompts an error whenever it reaches the line where it has to import a range into a two dimensional array:

```
Vendor = wb.Sheets("Output").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Value2
```

However, whenever run line by line (F8), the VBA code doesn't prompt any error at all.

To give some context, the objective of this code is to transpose rows of data into two columns and to, then, import these two columns into a two dimensional array for use in a loop.

It's a strange behavior that I have no clue as to how to explain it.

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Sub VendorFinder()

'variable declaration
Dim msg As String
Dim ans As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim DescRng As Range
Dim DescCol As Range
Dim VendorCol As Range
Dim j As Long
Dim Vendor As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sFile As String
Dim myVendor As Variant
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim VendorRng As Range
Dim r&, cnt&
Dim rangeroo As Range, rngRow As Range

On Error GoTo BadEntry

TryAgain:

'set columns
Set DescCol = Application.InputBox("Select Description Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set VendorCol = Application.InputBox("Select Vendor Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select First Row with Data", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

'set ranges
Set DescRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, DescCol.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, DescCol.Column).End(xlUp).Row, DescCol.Column))
Set VendorRng = Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, VendorCol.Column), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, DescCol.Column).End(xlUp).Row, VendorCol.Column))
myVendor = VendorRng.Value2

'import vendors
sFile = "D:\Desktop\Vendor List.xlsx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
Set rangeroo = wb.Sheets("Source").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
r = 1
For Each rngRow In rangeroo.Rows
    cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngRow.Cells)
    With wb.Sheets("Output").Cells(r, 1).Resize(cnt)
        .Value = rngRow.Cells(1).Value
        .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(rngRow.Resize(, cnt).Value)
    End With
    r = r + cnt
Next

Vendor = wb.Sheets("Output").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Value2

wb.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For Each rng In DescRng

    If Cells(rng.Row, VendorCol.Column).Value = "" Then

        For j = LBound(Vendor) To UBound(Vendor)

            If InStr(1, rng.Value, Vendor(j, 2), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                myVendor(rng.Row - FirstRow.Row + 1, 1) = Vendor(j, 1)

        Exit For

            End If

        Next j

    End If

Next rng

VendorRng.Resize(UBound(myVendor) - LBound(myVendor) + 1, 1) = myVendor

Exit Sub

BadEntry:

msg = "You have clicked on cancel for one of the prompts."
msg = msg & vbNewLine
msg = msg & "Do you wish to try again?"
ans = MsgBox(msg, vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation)
If ans = vbRetry Then Resume TryAgain

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a range you must add a sheet reference to every Range/Cells otherwise the active sheet is assumed.

Your code is equivalent to

```
Vendor = wb.Sheets("Output").Range(activesheet.Cells(1, 1), activesheet.Cells(activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Value2
```

and the error arises because you are referencing two different sheets (unless Output is the active sheet).

The neatest way around this is to use With (btw can simplify your expression too I think):

```
With wb.Sheets("Output")
    Vendor = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value2
End With
```

Comment: @BigBen - fair enough, I usually overlook it but can't do any harm and could avoid an error.

Comment: Still errors at `Vendor = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2)).Value2`

Comment: oops just realized my mistake